# Can an app still send notifications if running in the background is disabled?

Tags: android-10, background-process

I have some apps which show me promotional notifications of new features, deals, etc. I know I can turn these notifications off, but I tried disabling the app running in the background altogether instead (Android 10), so it does not run at all by itself unless I start it explicitly.

Apparently, some of these apps still send me suprise notifications from time to time. How is it possible? Can apps still work and send notifications even if they are not started by me and  cannot run in the background?

Answer (score 2):

That depends on which pushing mechanism your app uses.

In China, many applications use some pushing sdk, as long as there is one application using the same pushing sdk running, the pushing sdk will use the running application to launch stopped-running app(even force-stopped)  and make it running;

however, recently many chinese customized os has been modified to prevent this behavir

According to Google FCM(Google's pushing service), FCM won't send push message for forced-stopped application, but will do it for other situations.

So, according to this , you won't receive any notifications if you diable your application by force-stop

Comment: OP hasn't explicitly asked about push notifications. Notifications might also be local, not necessarily coming from a server. Apps can show scheduled notifications even from background.

Comment: @KevinDing Can you please link where you found the info about FCM and force-stopped apps?

Comment: https://groups.google.com/g/android-gcm/c/1J6XNVOzCcE?pli=1

Comment: why i mention pushing message not ordinary notification ，because every app company uses pushing message to send some news to users to trigger them openning the app，so they can get well look marketing data . and by using pushing messages as a trigger ，they can train users like a dog，let users get used to use their app ， aka get addicted. that's why pushing message is more important than native notices，because thery are targeted to youe habit
toktik is the typical one，by learning what you like ，keep send your likes， so your time is wasted.

Comment: That's absolutely correct. But only push notifications scenario partially answers the question. If you address the other half too, it'd be perfect :)

Comment: Not only in China: I have the same problem on lineage 20 (android 13) with a french app (I still get notifs even with background disabled)